# How can I write an ISO image to USB with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, iso, usb-drive

We are using PowerShell, and I have an ISO image that I want to write to a USB device.

In Unix using "dd" is very easy, and I've tried with third-party windows "rawrite.exe" but with mixed results.

Is there a way to do so using PowerShell internals only? Any cmdlet extension to do so?

Comment: To confirm your question, you have an ISO file.  You want powershell to extract that ISO to USB (i.e. as if burning the image to a CD/DVD, rather than just a file copy)?  FYI I've found a cmdlet which does the inverse of this (i.e. creating an ISO), so suspect the same library contains what you're after.  Sadly the links are down at the moment so I can't investigate further.  http://start-automating.com/

Answer (score 0):

If nothing already exists you could roll your own.

Here's a couple of starting points (c#):

- How to write a powershell cmdlet: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32999/How-to-Write-a-Custom-PowerShell-Cmdlet-Part-I
- How to extract an ISO: http://discutils.codeplex.com/

Alternatively 7zip allows you to extract iso files, so you could call that (or similar) via its command-line interface (by script) to achieve your purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of read and extract data from iso, you may actually mount the target iso as a disk image, and then copy files from the mounted drive to your target location.

This idea comes from the following URL.

http://www.codebroth.com/extracting-iso-images-with-powershell/